# Django Json Field Query

Tags: django

I've a JSONField in my model which is storing below types of data.

```
[
   {
      "name":"Name A",
      "type":"Type1",
      "class_type":"Class A"
   },
   {
      "name":"Name B",
      "type":"Type1",
      "class_type":"Class A"
   },
   {
      "name":"Name C",
      "type":"Type2",
      "class_type":"Class A"
   }
]
```

I've tried with the example of django documentation. But still return Null

I've tried with `SampleCategory.objects.filter(books__name = 'Name A')`

Comment: Is this a PostgreSQL database?

Comment: Yes. this a PostgreSQL database

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation, you can use `book__name` when you define the json data like this:

```
data = {
    "name":"Name A",
    "type":"Type1",
    "class_type":"Class A"
}

SampleCategory.objects.create(books=data)

SampleCategory.objects.filter(books__name = 'Name A')
```

Or if you define it like this as array:

```
data = [
   {
      "name":"Name A",
      "type":"Type1",
      "class_type":"Class A"
   },
   {
      "name":"Name B",
      "type":"Type1",
      "class_type":"Class A"
   },
   {
      "name":"Name C",
      "type":"Type2",
      "class_type":"Class A"
   }
]
SampleCategory.objects.create(books={'book':data})
SampleCategory.objects.filter(books__0__name = 'Name A')
```

If you have an array with simillar structured dictionary, then consider making separate model fields and create different entries. Like this:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    class_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

And use it as FK to `SampleCategory`:

```
class SampleCategory(models.Model):
    books = models.ForeignKey(Book)
```

Then you can query like the way you want in the given question( for example `SampleCategory.objects.filter(books__name = 'Name A')`). Hope it helps.